# androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0 Transformations.switchMap doesn' t work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appcompat, android-livedata-transformations

After i updated my build.gradle file and set the

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0" -> implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0"
```

I have a piece of code

```
override var serverIdContactId: MutableLiveData<Pair<Long, Int>> = MutableLiveData(null)
    override val contact: LiveData<Account>
        get() = Transformations.switchMap(serverIdContactId) {
            it?.let {
                accountsRepository.byId(it.first, it.second)
            }
        }
```

and after setting the pair `serverIdContactId`, the Transformation never gets triggered!
What does have changed?

Comment: So where do you `observe` your `contact` LiveData?

Comment: i do in my main activity. The problem is that when i updated the  dependency the observer never triggers